# Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG network card wifi not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers

I recently installed Xubuntu on my laptop, dual booted with Windows.

Everything works perfectly on the Windows side, but Xubuntu for some reason either doesn't recognise or can't access my network card, so I can't connect to the wifi. I have updated the Kernel and Ubuntu itself, I have checked for driver updates for my network card and I couldn't find any (it's a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG).

I know almost nothing about Linux and Ubuntu so I am clueless on how to solve this but I really need it to work as fast as possible so all help would be highly appreciated.

Edit:

`lshw -c net`

```
*-network DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 24:0a:64:cb:f1:7f
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.16.0-41-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:18 memory:f7900000-f797ffff memory:f7980000-f798ffff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 10
   serial: bc:ee:7b:46:f6:ed
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:52 memory:f7800000-f783ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux XubuntoV2 3.16.0-41-generic #57~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 18 18:01:13 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`rfkill list all`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no

4: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 1):

Used this command:

```
echo "blacklist acer_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then this one:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Set the option

```
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

Then saved it, did `unblock all`

```
rfkill unblock all
```

and restarted, works perfectly now.

Comment: I'm running Zorin OS Ultimate for the past 3 months. I couldn't get to enable my wireless on my Acer Aspire. Zorin support is of no use. Tried so many suggestions, nothing worked, so I gave up. So I've been using usb tethering to have internet connection. Now, after 3 months, I Wasn't so busy so I started searching again for the solution. And finally stumbled upon this post. The ath9k.conf solution worked for me! Thank you so much! now my BT and Wifi are both working! Thank you @eXistance !!!!