# no wlan0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, atheros

Hi I must use Wifi using Ubuntu on my laptop
but there is no wlan0, no wireless connection.

Im using 'Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter'
I cant find it using lspci, so checked it on my Window.

And using VMware14, Ubuntu 16.04 32bits

Plz help me........
My output is....

```
ifconfig -a
ens33     Link encap:Ethernet 
          HWaddr 00:0c:29:28:5e:35  
          inet addr:192.168.0.17
          Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a48:e6e8:b4ea:594d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:84 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10268 (10.2 KB)  TX bytes:13232 (13.2 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:205 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:205 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:16030 (16.0 KB)  TX bytes:16030 (16.0 KB)



lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX Host bridge (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX AGP bridge (rev 01)
00:07.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ISA (rev 08)
00:07.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:07.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:07.7 System peripheral: VMware Virtual Machine Communication Interface (rev 10)
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
00:10.0 SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic 53c1030 
PCI-X Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI (rev 01)
00:11.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI bridge (rev 02)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
02:00.0 USB controller: VMware USB1.1 UHCI Controller
02:01.0 Ethernet controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] (rev 10)
02:02.0 Multimedia audio controller: Ensoniq ES1371 / Creative Labs CT2518/ES1373 (rev 02)
02:03.0 USB controller: VMware USB2 EHCI Controller
02:05.0 SATA controller: VMware SATA AHCI controller
```

And I thought this is because there is no wireless LAN drive on my Ubuntu
so I did it following commands but it doesnt work.

```
sudo su
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
cd /usr/src/
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4-rc2/backports-4.4-rc2-1.tar.gz
tar xvf backports-3.12.2-1.tar.bz2
cd backports-3.12.2-1
make defconfig-ath9k
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: `ens33` is the name of your wired connection and it is called "Predictable interfaces names"  Related https://askubuntu.com/questions/628217/use-of-predictable-network-interface-names-with-alternate-kernels   also see https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/  Nothing wrong there.

Comment: Regarding the wireless. See if this works: https://askubuntu.com/a/643704/15811

Comment: I tried  askubuntu.com/a/643704/15811 but it doesnt work and result was nothing after rkfill ~ command..

Comment: @Wiking nothing for both of them...

Comment: @Wiking I used wirelss USB, and it didnt work at first, but after I upgraded to VMware pro, it worked! thx a lot Wiking!